# power off dialog pops on every keystroke on newly installed ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: 20.04

I installed ubuntu 20.04.3 alongside Windows 10. No issue with grub and boot loading. But when trying to log into ubuntu, the "power off" dialog with its three options (restart, lock, shut down) pops on. Yes, on every single keystroke, the "power off" dialog pops up. Even when I dismiss it with mouse and finally log into ubuntu and try to use my keyboard, this keeps happening.

I'm using a new and rather high end Asus laptop. I tried reinstalling ubuntu, formatting partitions and installing again, creating a new bootable usb, and downloading the ubuntu iso file again. None helped.

Comment: Does this happen with a different keyboard? Like, plug in a USB keyboard, and see if the issue still happens. If it doesn't, something is wrong with your keyboard/hardware.

Comment: weird. what happens when you login via the shell? if you can, what happens when you run the command `xev`?

Comment: I assume nothing odd / similar is happening when you boot in to windows?

Comment: @cocomac Interesting observation. No usb keyboard works fine. It seems that the kernel is not compatible with my laptop's keyboard driver.

Comment: @Will No windows works fine. Even after ubuntu installation.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I have the exact same problem and I am using an ASUS ROG laptop. BIZARRELY IT DOESN'T HAPPEN WHEN I USE THE SHIFT KEY. (not much help when writing code)

Comment: @unpickme Nope! I gave up on it as it appeared the issue is coming from a lower level component (like kernel or some core linux component). Have you tried Ubuntu 22.04?